# Interactive Github Markdown Checkboxes (Task Lists)

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

> Task lists render as read-only checkboxes in Markdown files.

https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-task-lists

Is there a sneaky way to make the checkboxes interactive in Markdown files? I don't need it to remember state, I just want to have a helpful work checklist:

1. [ ] Remove hard drive
2. [ ] Remove RAM
3. [ ] Remove CPU

I don't care if it loses state on a page reload, I'll keep the page up while I work through it and if I otherwise lose data, it's not a big deal.

I tried inserting HTML form check boxes, and that worked locally, but is filtered out by GitHub.

Comment: In Markdown file only way to mark the checkbox is by editing the md file and put [x] in the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Task lists render as read-only checkboxes in Markdown files. People with write permissions in the repository can edit the file to select or unselect the checkboxes.

[About task lists](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-task-lists)